# Fix carousel caption on slide in react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, carousel

I want to fix the caption text on the carousel. The text should change. But it can't be slide with image. Here is a working example of how i did this. but the text change on slide is not working as expected. sometimes is works fine sometimes it doesn't.

https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap4-carousel-forked-y4htnn?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: which line of code do you write change?

Comment: there is so many things i changed to get it threre